# double spit txt file by new line and ";"

Tags: javascript, select, split

I have to douple split my txt file. The txt file looks like

```
1; Kategorija1
2; Kategorija2
3; Kategorija3 
4; ...
```

I need to put this in select which I have succeeded  but I did manage only splitting new line. I need to split both new line and **`";"`** putting text in select and saving id ("1;") in value of select..

```
function readAll()
{
  var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
  var txtFile = fso.OpenTextFile("kategorije.txt", 1, false, 0);         

  var fText = txtFile.ReadAll();  
  txtFile.Close();  
  fso = null  
  var array = fText.split("\r\n");
  var sel = document.getElementById("dropdown2");
  for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
  {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.innerHTML = array[i];
    opt.value = array[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
  }
}
```

Comment: should the o/p be like this `["1 Kategorija1", "2 Kategorija", "3 Kategorija3"]` ?

Comment: No i need IDs only to do smt else which i'll do later i just need txt in options but ID in values so i can work later with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fText.replace(/(\d;)/g,"").split("\n"); //to get the option text ["Kategorija1", "Kategorija", "Kategorija3"]
fText.match(/(\d;)/g) //to get id  ["1;", "2;", "3;"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/24XSa/

Comment: it works perfectly ty alot u saved my day
p.s. im still new here so i cant vote up anyway thxs for help

Comment: :) Its okay, you will have to press F12 to see the console in the browser after opening that link by the way

Comment: yea yea  txhs again ;-)

Comment: i hope u will see this :D 
now i need to split smt like this 
1;1; Podkategorija1
2;1; Podkategorija2
3;2; Podkategorija3
4;2; Podkategorija4
5;3; Podkategorija5
6;3; Podkategorija6
same shit i need to split both ; and newline sry for bothering but im so newbie with regexp

Comment: use `/(\d;){2}/g` for that.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    var newarray=array[i].split(';')
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.innerHTML = newarray[0];
    opt.value = newarray[0];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}
```